# How to output contents of raw files

Tags: logging, resources, inputstream

I'm just working through a chapter on Managing Application Resources and am having a bit of trouble with the following:

> "Add a raw text file resource to the Droid1 project. Use the openRawResourse() method to create an InputStream object and read the file. Output the contents of the file by using Log.v() method. Rerun the application and view the result."

So firstly, I right clicked on the res folder, created a new raw folder and dragged a txt file from my desktop into this (think this was ok and couldn't find another way of importing the file).

Then I wrote these two lines:

```
InputStream iFile = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.textfile);
Log.v(TAG, iFile);
```

However I get the error:

> "The method v(String, String) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, InputStream)"

Not sure what to do... any suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error indicates the second parameter for the v method needs to be of the String data type. So you need to convert the InputStream iFile to a string.

I referenced http://www.kodejava.org/examples/266.html

You'll need the following imports in your Activity:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
```

And the method itself:

```
public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {

    /* To convert the InputStream to String we use the
    * Reader.read(char[] buffer) method. We iterate until the
    * Reader return -1 which means there's no more data to
    * read. We use the StringWriter class to produce the string.*/
    if (is != null) {
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
    try {
        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
        int n;
        while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
    return writer.toString();
    } else {        
        return "";
    }

}
```

Pass your InputStream into the method to get your String, and Log.v

```
InputStream iFile = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.textfile);
String strInput = null;
try {
  strInput = convertStreamToString(iFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
  Log.v(TAG, "The string conversion failed.");
}
if(strInput != null){
  Log.v(TAG, strInput);
}
```